# SharePoint 2010 Search DB restore

Tags: 2010, sharepoint-server, search, restore

In SharePoint 2010 "Search_Service_Application_CrawlStoreDB" DB is having consistency errors and we want to restore that DB from earlier backups.

What should the restore sequence as restoring that DB alone might create inconsistency across the search DB?

Comment: You may want to take a look at the answer provided by Waqas in this question I asked a few months ago: https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/231837/dbcc-checkdb-corruption-in-search-service-application-crawlstoredb

Comment: Did the restoration worked for you? or creating a new DB is best approach?

Comment: Answering right now, but a simple restore did the trick!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We had to do it last month because our Search_Service_Application_CrawlDB was corrupted (On SharePoint 2013), and simply restoring it and start a `Full Crawl` did the trick. It didn't cause any inconsistancies and the search is now working fine.

And no, you cannot avoid the `Full Crawl` like said in this post: [full crawl keeps auto starts even though it is only scheduled for later](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/123685/full-crawl-keeps-auto-starts-even-though-it-is-only-scheduled-for-later) (Can't found the Microsoft Article about that right now, but I'm sure I saw one...)